# Compute the Sum of the Degrees of All Vertices and count Number of Edges

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Can someone help me understand this problem? 
The question asks: For the following three graphs, 
(a) compute the sum of the degrees of all the vertices, 
(b) count the number of edges and look for a pattern for how the answers to (a) and (b) are related.

The graph is below
[image]

I have no idea how to solve for sum of degrees when there are no numbers given in that graph. Additionally, the materials I am reading on sum of degrees is difficult to comprehend. I would love to get a Layman's term style of understanding how to go about solving this problem.

Comment: What numbers do you need *in the graphs*? Do you know what "degree" means?

Comment: Is degree what we know in geometry (0 to 360) ? I'm hoping this is what the question is asking. As for the numbers, the question didn't give me any.

Comment: No, "degree" for graphs means something completely different. The degree of a node is the number of connected edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The degree of a node is th number of connected lines. Look at the following picture to got a feeling for what I mean. The upper red node is of degree two because two lines (edges) are connected. The middle green one is of degree three, because it touches three lines.

[image]
Just sum up all degrees of all nodes to find your result.

Comment: Would the number of edges also be the sum of the degrees?

Comment: nvm I got it. It's half of the sum of degree. Thank you, I appreciate it!

Comment: @miiworld2 Exactly ;) That's the famous [handshaking lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma).

Answer (score 1):

The degree of a vertex (dot) is the number of edges (lines) that touch the vertex.

> For any graph the sum of the degrees of the vertices equals twice the number of edges (Euler, $1736$).